# Which main TNG character has spent the most episodes 'absent'?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

So, I was thinking that most episodes, we see all of the *TNG* cast every episode, but surely there are some episodes where some characters aren't seen.  So, my question is **which of the main characters from *TNG* had the most episodes where they were *not seen* in the episode?**

By main, I'm referring to:

- Picard
- Riker
- LaForge
- Data
- Troi
- Worf
- Crusher
- Pulaski

Now, some restrictions:

- Dr Pulaski only counts in the confines of Season 2 i.e. if she was absent in 12 episodes from season 2 and the next character in this ranking was absent for 11 episodes in the entire series, then she would count.  In short, **her absence in all seasons but for season 2 doesn't count**
- Similarly, Dr Crusher's absence from Season 2 doesn't count
- Tasha Yar's absence following her death doesn't count.

Comment: Interesting, [IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0092455/) suggests that Crusher might be the only one, but that's probably because of Season 2!

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a duplicate

Comment: I had thought a while back to ask the opposite of this question (which character features in the most episodes), but never got around to it. Feel free to use it if you wish.

Comment: @Xantec thanks; appreciate the offer, but I'm perfectly happy for you to ask it; it was your question after all!

Comment: Pulaski gets a pass, but Guinan doesn't? I'm fairly sure that Guinan would win this one. (I was going to write an answer but it looks as though your criteria excludes her...)

Comment: @lunchmeat317 considering she spends most episodes as a side character than one of the main characters consistently I've excluded her from the scope of this question

Comment: Meaney doesn't even have a name until season two. I guess it's fitting that he's not on the list. He was in "over 50 episodes" out of 178....

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It's either Deanna Troi or Geordi La Forge, depending on exactly what you count as an absence.

### Counselor Troi

There are ten episodes where Marina Sirtis doesn't appear in any capacity:

1. ["Hide and Q"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Hide_and_Q_(episode))
2. ["Datalore"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Datalore_(episode))
3. ["11001001"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/11001001_(episode))
4. ["Heart of Glory"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Heart_of_Glory_(episode))
5. ["A Matter of Honor"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/A_Matter_Of_Honor_(episode))
6. ["Identity Crisis"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Identity_Crisis_(episode))
7. ["The Perfect Mate"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Perfect_Mate_(episode))
8. ["The Inner Light"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Inner_Light_(episode))
9. ["Birthright, Part 1"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Birthright,_Part_II_(episode))
10. ["Rightful Heir"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Rightful_Heir_(episode))

### Geordi La Forge

Geordi's absences range from six to eleven, depending on how you count.

There are six episodes where LeVar Burton doesn't appear in any capacity:

1. ["A Matter of Honor"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/A_Matter_Of_Honor_(episode))
2. ["Manhunt"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Manhunt_(episode))
3. ["Captain's Holiday"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Captain%27s_Holiday_(episode))
4. ["First Contact"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/First_Contact_(episode))
5. ["Rightful Heir"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Rightful_Heir_(episode))
6. ["Attached"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Attached_(episode))

There are two additional episodes where Geordi appears only as a hallucination or hologram:

7. ["Frame of Mind"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Frame_of_Mind_(episode))
8. ["Thine Own Self"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Thine_Own_Self_(episode))

There are two more episodes where LeVar Burton doesn't appear on-camera, but his voice is heard:

9. ["The Wounded"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Wounded_(episode))
10. ["Tapestry"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Tapestry_(episode))

And there's one episode where stock footage of Burton is used:

11. ["Suddenly Human"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Suddenly_Human_(episode))